# How can I better focus my question?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

My question [Aggregate count of method calls within program run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63502663/aggregate-count-of-method-calls-within-program-run) has been closed as requiring more focus:

> Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.

The question might be a touch unclear, but to my understanding there is only a single problem in the question. What sort of feedback is being requested here?

Comment: Don't you think 'how can I do this?' sounds a bit.... Large as a problem statement? This is way more than ONE problem. You say 'how do I do X?' would likely be better to have 'Im trying Y to do X. According to what I can find, it should give me 'Z'. But I got a squirrel. What gives?'.

Comment: @Patrice Not necessarily, because AFAICT the problem itself is sufficiently narrow. _I have two numbers that I want to add together. How do I this?_ is similarly narrow. Admittedly, the question is not quite as narrow as that, but I think it can be answered in a paragraph or two.

Comment: You seem to have a compiled binary with no source code.  How is disentangling that remotely similar to adding two numbers together?

Comment: I mean.... If it's that simple.... Try it? Come back when you hit a snag? Isn't that how Stack is supposed to be? (Really don't mean to be dismissive. It's just the *enough research* criteria seems to not really be as high as it used to be. I wonder how much research and trials went into the original question.)

Comment: .. and that is before considerations like 'who owns the IP and do you have permission to hack it?'

Comment: Yeah, it's only a couple of paragraphs, so how hard can it be? (sorry Clarkson:).

Comment: @MartinJames I have the source to my own binaries. What interests me is the internal calls to public methods within the third party library and the BCL; once I'm doing that, applying the technique to my own compiled library is a no-brainer. I don't think it's a violation of any IP to parse the IL of the binary; and any decent CPU profiler will do the same thing.

Comment: @MartinJames Well, if I knew which paragraphs, then I wouldn't be asking the question, would I? :)

Comment: I am not the brightest star in the sky... but it seems to me like you are asking how to profile an application, but instead of using an existing profiler to do it you want to write code yourself to do it, like creating a self-profiling application? I am not surprised that given this very high level question, people are puzzled what you would expect from an answer. Hence... not a focused question. For focused questions it is clear what the desired answer is.

Comment: @Gimby You're absolutely right. Except that I didn't get any answers when I asked about [using an existing profiler which does provide this information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63363805/111794).